# WebDriver with Java - click image to open a link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On click of a href image I need to open a link on the page . The link appears to be within a href tag.

I tried to open the link using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.classItem")).click();` but page seems like it doesn't work either. I am using google chrome driver.

Could you please let me know what I need to do?

Below is my code

HTML code:

```
<a class="className" href="#">
 <img src="item.png" class="classItem" width="20" height="20">
 <span>Item</span>
</a>
```

Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.classItem")).click();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='className']/img")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `href` is in the parent `<a>`. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.className")).click();
```

Comment: @arunks do you have any error? or is it just clicking without doing anything?

Comment: it opens page but not doing anything after that

Comment: @arunks in new window?

Comment: My usual webpage open and stays there, it doesnt click the a href link to open the link

Comment: @arunks can you add to the question the code from the beginning of the test to the clicking on the href? I suspect the problem is before the clicking.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many hyperlink on page that might be having same class name.
 While targeting such one, the first element in the document might get targeted when using class name only.
So based on unique attribute value, you can locate the element [Reference Link](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.className img[src='item.png']")).click();
```